# How can I force a request to the server for a given state?

Tags: javascript, angular-ui-router

When the user navigates to `/admin/logout`, I want to make sure that the request is actually made, instead, I get redirected to `/admin` because I have a `.otherwise` definition:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise( "/admin" );
```

When I define a state for the `/admin/logout` route, the state is invoked, but that still doesn't cause `/admin/logout` to be actually requested from the server.

I want to avoid creating a controller and calling `/admin/logout` through `$http` because it seems overly complicated for what I actually want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up simply reloading the page when the state is invoked.

The key for simplicity here is to simply provide `window.location.reload` as the controller for the state:

```
function configureApplication( $stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode( true );

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise( "/admin" );

    $stateProvider
        .state( "logout", {
            url        : "/admin/logout",
            controller : window.location.reload.bind( window.location, true )
        } );
}
```